# UIPasteboardChangedNotification called twice when copying content from webview

Tags: ios, notifications, uipasteboard

There was an issue that when copying content from a webview, the notification "UIPasteboardChangedNotification" will be called twice. Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This notification might indeed fire 2 times when copying content from a webview. You could check if the notification is fired due to an item being added:

```
- (void) pasteboardChangedNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if(notification.userInfo != NULL && [notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIPasteboardChangedTypesAddedKey] != NULL) {
        //item added
    }
    else {
        //nothing added
    }
}
```